# Flutter Doctor, Android licenses status unknown

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Flutter doctor says that my android license status cannot be found.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.450], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit
      https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.48.2)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

I did try running flutter doctor --android-licenses
that returned me with the following error

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Flutter 2.2.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

Framework • revision f4abaa0735 (7 days ago) • 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700

Engine • revision 241c87ad80

Tools • Dart 2.13.4

Running flutter doctor...

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale es-ES)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)

✗ Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

I have achived the solution on the next way:

**1.- Open a terminal window.**

**2.- Set the environemnt var JAVA_HOME to the path where the jdk 8 ist. in my case is:**
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home

**3.- Run the command:** flutter doctor --android-licenses

Thesethree steps haven resolved my problem.

flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale es-ES)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

Answer (score 0):

Save the value of your JAVA_HOME environment variable, then remove the JAVA_HOME environment variable if it exists.

Save the value of your jdk path. Remove your jdk from your PATH.

With those changes made, the flutter doctor --android-licenses should work.

If applicable, restore your JAVA_HOME environment variable and jdk in your path.

If that doesn't work, uninstall Android Studio and XCode, download the latest copies and reinstall.

If you can't resolve the issue, look at this thread: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28230

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It turned out to be an issue with java version. apparently java 11 does not support flutter atm. downgrading to java 8 worked for me